# How does scanning for routers work?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

When a wifi enabled device like a laptop scans the area for wireless routers, it sends out some sort of electromagnetic wave (or listens for electromagnetic waves, possibly), and then a list of nearby routers appears.

1. Physically speaking, who starts the conversation? Does the device send out waves and receive responses from routers? Or are routers continuously emitting signals, and your device just picks them up?
2. Assuming the router is in range, why does the computer add it to its list of available routers? What needs to happen for the computer to say "oh, this thing is a router"? Does the router need to send back a specific handshake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. WiFi access-points (and routers) send out a [SSID](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_an_SSID) periodically. Your computer/device just picks this up and sees that there is an available WiFi access-point. Your device does not send anything out until that point. Often (if not always) you can disable the broadcast of the SSID in the WiFi-router. If the computer does not have the network in its list it has no knowledge of it existence.
2. At the moment a new network (SSID) is detected it is added to the list. There is no need for communication yet. If you get out of range the SSID is cleared from the list. But if you did have communications with the router it is added to the list permanently. The SSID is all that's needed to it being added to that list.